# Texture is not fully displayed on some devices, but doing well in others, using cocos2d-x

Tags: android, textures, cocos2d-x

I this application, which is a simple game, it loads texture file from the resources.

The texture is not fully displayed on device [Allwinner a13 9 inch, Android 4.0]

However, in another device [Nexus 7, Android 4.2.1], it works perfectly.

Just wondering what is this problem could be. Thanks!!

BTW: I am using cocos2d-x

Answer (score 0):

resolution of allwinner is less than nexus so i think that this difference made the mess and you should use retina desplay and other options in cocos2d-x for doing the job.